# RxJS: map promise result and promise error to different values

Tags: javascript, rxjs

The following code effectively maps promise resolution to `true` and a promise error to `false`.

```
onlineUpdate$
.switchMap(online => {
  switch (online) {
    default:
    case true: {
      const connected$ = new Rx.Subject();
      axios.get("/some/url/to/test/connection")
        .then(response => connected$.next(true))
        .catch(error => connected$.next(false));
      return connected$;
    }
    case false: {
      return Rx.Observable.of(false);
    }
  }
});
```

But something about creating the intermediate `Rx.Subject` feels like I'm doing more work than I need to. Is there a more elegant or built-in way to map promise resolution to one value and promise error to another without the use of an intermediate `Rx.Subject` or other observable?

Comment: While in this particular case not much can happen, I still would [recommend `.then(…, …)` over `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there's no need to use `Observable.fromPromise()` at all. The most straightforward change to make this work is:

```
onlineUpdate$
.switchMap(online => {
  switch (online) {
    default:
    case true: {
      return axios.get("/some/url/to/test/connection")
        .then(response => true)
        .catch(error => false);
    }
    case false: {
      return Rx.Observable.of(false);
    }
  }
});
```

Or, if you prefer ternaries over `switch` statements:

```
onlineUpdate$
.switchMap(online => {
  return online ?
    axios.get("/some/url/to/test/connection")
      .then(response => true)
      .catch(error => false)
    : Rx.Observable.of(false);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the Promise into an Observable via [**Observable#fromPromise**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise) function and pass the the promise into. Observable will emit `true` if the Promise is resolved or `false` if it is rejected

```
...
case true: {
      return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(axios.get("/some/url/to/test/connection")
                                            .then(response => true)
                                            .catch(error => false));
    }
...
```

Simple Example.

`Rx.Observable.of(false`) is equivalent to the `case false`.
`Promise.resolve(true)` to the `then` function of the promise and `Promise.reject('Error').catch(err => false)` to the `catch` function of the promise.

```js
Rx.Observable.of(false).subscribe(console.log);
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve(true)).subscribe(console.log);
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.reject('Error').catch(err => false)).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.5.2/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Suren. This indeed helped me get rid of the Rx.Subject(). However, it turns out the use of `Observable.fromPromise` isn't needed with `flatMap` or `switchMap`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just return `Observable.of(false)` in the catch block of the `Observable.fromPromise()`. Like wise, use `.map()` to return `Observable.of(true)` if the connection is successful.

```
onlineUpdate$
    .switchMap(online => {
        switch (online) {
            default:
            case true: {
                Rx.Observable.fromPromise(axios.get("/some/url/to/test/connection"))
                    .map(() => true) // if the promise resolves to something, return an Observable.of(true)
                    .catch(() => Rx.Observable.of(false)) // else if there is any error return Observable.of(false)
            }
            case false: {
                return Rx.Observable.of(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Note that you have to explicitly `.map()` the `Observable.fromPromise` to true if the `promise` resolves successfully.

You can write the code in a much more succinct way:

```
onlineUpdate$
    .switchMap(online => {
        return online ?
            Rx.Observable.fromPromise(axios.get("/some/url/to/test/connection"))
                .map(() => true)
                .catch(() => Observable.of(false))
            : Observabe.of(false)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `switchMap` operator works with so-called [Observable input](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObservableInputDoc.html) which means you can just return the Promise without turning it into an Observable:

```
onlineUpdate$
.switchMap(online => {
  switch (online) {
    default:
    case true: {
      return axios.get("/some/url/to/test/connection");
    }
    case false: {
      return Rx.Observable.of(false);
    }
  }
})
.catch(() => Rx.Observable.of(false))
.map(Boolean) // force convert to boolean
```

Just be aware this isn't the same as what you wrote. The `catch` operator will catch all errors even if they don't come from the preceding `axios.get` call but maybe it doesn't matter in your case.